# What's making my page extend slightly beyond the viewport? [CSS]

Tags: css, xhtml, viewport

Basically I'm a tad confused. You'll see at http://furnace.howcode.com , in the second column, the bottom scrollbar button is extended slightly beyond the end of the viewport. I'm pretty confused as I've been examining the CSS and can't find anything that's causing this.

Can you have a look? It's probably something simple that I've just missed! :)

Screenshot:

[image: hmmm...?]
<sub>(source: [droplr.com](http://files.droplr.com/files/49111734/XWqC.hurrr.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you have used a fixed pixel height on `#tabscontainer` but a percentage on `#ajaxresults`. Resizing the window will show (or cut) more of the scrollbar since 90px won't always be 10% of the viewport.

The easiest way to fix this is to set `#tabscontainer` to have `height:10%`.

**EDIT:** Just noticed your comment about the tabs being a fixed height. Looking for an alternative fix.

Okay, found a fix though I haven't tested this in IE so you may want to have a look at that ;)

1. Give `#col2` a `position:relative`
2. Remove `height:90%`, `min-height:90%` and `max-height:90%` from `#ajaxresults`.
3. Give `#ajaxresults`: `position:absolute`, `top:90px` and `bottom:0`.

Try that out and it should work as intended, but like I said I haven't checked IE so you may need to do a little more hacking to get it to work there.

Comment: Thanks akamike. Really appreciate you searching for an extra fix.

Comment: Updated my answer but retaining original answer as I feel the information is relevant to debugging the issue.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Thank you so much akamike! This works perfectly. Great fix.

Just checked it out in Adobe Browserlab (I'm on a Mac so testing in IE isn't easy...) - It (obviously) fails in IE6. IE7 works - but extends beyond the viewport with scrollbars (works but not ideal). And it works fine in IE8. My target market are web designers so it's not really likely they'll be using IE7 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Height on `#tabscontainer` element.

```
#tabscontainer {
 background-color:black;
 height:90px;
 max-width:529px;
 min-width:326px;
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 width:100%;
}
```

Try:

```
#tabscontainer {
 height:30px;
 ...
}
```

Follow-up on comment:

Decrease the `#ajaxresults` height then:

```
#ajaxresults  {
   height:70%;
   max-height:70%
   ...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but #tabscontainer has to be 90px in height, as there will be some graphical 90px-high tab images to go there shortly...

Comment: You can Decrease the `#ajaxresults` height then, but if you set it in % it will probably do the same again on smaller browser window